# how to set many mysql selecting queries in a function in django views.py

Tags: django

I'm not sure if the question title is ok or need to be changed but my problem is this:

In views.py file:

```
def four(request):
    mavared1 = PDivContent.objects.filter(chest='1', divv='1')
    mavared2 = PDivContent.objects.filter(chest='1', divv='2')
    return render(request, 'four.html', {'mavared1': mavared1, 'mavared2': mavared2})
```

And in four.html:

```
<div id="first">
     {% for i in mavared1 %}
         <li>{{ i.txt }}</li>
     {% endfor %}
</div>


<div id="second">
     {% for i in mavared2 %}
         <li>{{ i.txt }}</li>
     {% endfor %}
</div>
```

And the output of the code is something like this:

(for mavared1):

```
red
blue
black
pink
```

(for mavared2):

```
a
b
c
d
```

I have set mavared1 and mavared2 in my views.py function manually. Its ok for now that there is only 2, mavared1 and mavared2, but what if I have 50?!

Do I have to type like this: ??!!

```
mavared1 = PDivContent.objects.filter(chest='1', divv='1')
.
.
mavared50 = PDivContent.objects.filter(chest='1', divv='50')
```

Is there any other way?!

Comment: What are they supposed to be doing? you're making N queries at the minute so you should figure out what you actually want to be displaying and find a loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course not, you write loops and use data structures `dict` to do that:

```
def four(request):
    divv = [str(i) for i in range(1, 51)]
    marvared_dict = {}
    for divv in divvs:
        marvared_dict[divv] = PDivContent.objects.filter(chest='1', divv=divv)
    return render(request, 'four.html', {'marvared_dict': marvared_dict})
```

four.html

```
{% for divv, marvareds in marvared_dict.items %}
<div id="{{ divv }}">
     {% for i in mavareds %}
         <li>{{ i.txt }}</li>
     {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thats still making `n` queries which is just horrible

Comment: @Sayse I think OP wants to display records in groups by certain criteria(`divv` value in this case), I can't imagine what can you do without actually querying each `divv` to get records.

Comment: You could just make one query and iterate over that, I'm guesing thats why the op was asking about forloop.counter in [their last "question"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36619294/1324033)

Comment: It helped @Shang Wang, but there is a problem. the mavared_dict will be filled with unregular indexes... I mean like this `{'1': [<PDivContent: red>, <PDivContent: pink>,'2': [<PDivContent: black>, <PDivContent: white>,'5': [<PDivContent: green>, <PDivContent: blue>,'3': [<PDivContent: gray>, <PDivContent: yellow>,'5': [<PDivContent: orange>, <PDivContent: silver>}`